# How do I repair my truck?

Tags: cross-country-canada

So there I am! Trucking about Canada, free as can be. Suddenly, my truck breaks down. I can't go anywhere to fix it, because my truck is broken, but I don't know what else to do. How can I fix my truck, so I can keep on trucking?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, the command `CALL TOW` will call a tow truck.  I forget exactly what you do after that, but I'm pretty sure you need to do this to get back on track.

Answer (score 1):

you need to "radio for help", the tow truck will come fix you up